# Como fazer um método retornar uma string em Java

Tags: java, array

Quero criar um programa que leia o nome e a idade de uma pessoa e compare as idades e por fim mostre o nome da pessoa mais velha. Meu raciocínio foi comparar qual é a maior e retornar o índice da posição do *array*. Mas o retorno é sempre 0. E também eu não sei como pegar o retorno e mostra o conteúdo do *array* na posição.

```
package Lista1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pessoa {
    private static String nome;
    private static int idade;

    public static int comparaIdade(Pessoa[] pessoa){

        int maior=0;
        int ind = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            if(pessoa[i].idade>maior){
                maior=pessoa[i].idade;
                ind=i;
            }
        }
        return ind;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pessoa[] pessoa = new Pessoa[3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa: ");
            pessoa[i].nome = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite a idade da pessoa: ");
            pessoa[i].idade = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.printf("Nome da pessoa mais velha: %d", comparaIdade(pessoa));

    }



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se deseja que retorne o nome, deve fazer isto e não retornar o índice como estava fazendo.

Tem vários outros erros aí. Está misturando a pessoa com o algoritmo, está criando membros estáticos onde devem ser de instância, não está instanciando um objeto antes de usá-lo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pessoa {
    public String nome;
    public int idade;
}
class Programa {
    public static String comparaIdade(Pessoa[] pessoa){
        int maior = pessoa[0].idade;
        int indice = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println(pessoa[i].idade);
            if (pessoa[i].idade > maior) {
                maior = pessoa[i].idade;
                indice = i;
            }
        }
        return pessoa[indice].nome;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pessoa[] pessoa = new Pessoa[3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            pessoa[i] = new Pessoa();
            System.out.println("Digite o nome da pessoa: ");
            pessoa[i].nome = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Digite a idade da pessoa: ");
            pessoa[i].idade = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.printf("Nome da pessoa mais velha: %s", comparaIdade(pessoa));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ic193K). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ndfbfnlg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Oldest.java).

Comment: Está retornando sempre a última posição do array.

Comment: É o que eu falei, o seu código tem outros erros, não é só o que eu mostrei na resposta. Você não está criando 3 nomes, está criando 1 e sobrepondo ele, por isso fica sempre o último.

Comment: Consertei os erros principais.