# Converter Números Romanos

Tags: java, lógica

eu sei que já fiz uma pergunta sobre o mesmo tema, porém, surgiu uma outra dúvida. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que converte números inteiros para números romanos, como vocês podem ver no código abaixo ... Mas, a jTextField1 ESTÁ RETORNANDO OUTROS NÚMEROS, como vocês podem ver na imagem, alguém tem alguma idéia do que pode ser? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
    private void btnConverterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        int[] vaNum = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

        String[] vaRom = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

        int numero = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        System.out.printf("%-4d ", numero);
        int i = 0;
        while (numero > 0) {
            if (numero >= vaNum[i]) {
                jTextField1.setText(vaRom[i]);
                numero -= vaNum[i];
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual a relação desse daqui com esse outro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247563/64969?

Comment: É sobre o mesmo programa

Comment: eu não entendi a diferença entre as perguntas, os títulos estão muito semelhantes. Qual a diferença entre as perguntas? Se a outra pergunta é relacionada e importante, é de bom grado deixar ela linkada junto com um texto seu explicando como elas conservam

Comment: Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245213/64969

Comment: Na outra o programa simplesmente não funcionava, nesta há apenas um erro ... como citado acima

Comment: Você sabe que o `setText` substitui o texto anterior, certo? Então toda essa iteração está sendo descartada em detrimento da última operação realizada. Por que não retornar a `String` para com esse resultado setar o texto? E de qualquer sorte, seu texto me está confuso

Comment: Amigo, não entendi o que está querendo dizer, estou apenas começando no mundo Java, pode ser mais claro por favor? Como retornar a String?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235774/64969

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnConverterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int[] vaNum = {1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1};

    String[] vaRom = {"M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"};

    public String resposta;

    int numero = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    System.out.printf("%-4d ", numero);
    int i = 0;
    while (numero > 0) {
        if (numero >= vaNum[i]) {
            resposta += vaRom[i];
            numero -= vaNum[i];
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    jTextField1.setText(resposta);
}
```

Comment: Pode deixar mais claro onde colocar e o que apagar no código?

Comment: Criar a variavel reaposta antes do while, trocar o seu while por esse depois colocar o meu setText depois do while

Comment: Cara, o erro está no System.ou.printf("%-4d", numero);

Comment: O código que você me passou está cheio de erros

Comment: O erro está no 20 ou no X? Eu editei a resposta depois e deichei o código menor colocou o novo ou o anterior?

Comment: O erro está no X, era para aparecer XX ...

Comment: O printf serve para escrever na saida o valor da variável número não? E pela imagem está funcionando corretamente. Qual o problema com ele?

Comment: Isso mesmo, tem razão ... Mas a saída está errada, 20 em números romanos é XX ... não tenho ideia de onde está o erro ...

Comment: Imagino que o erro está no `jTextField1.setText(vaRom[i]);` ja que quando ele passa pela primeira vez seta X no textfield e na segunda vez ele seta X de novo sobre escrevendo em vez de colocar mais um X, por isso criei uma variavel resposta e adicionei a variavel resposta X com += sem sobre escrevela e depois setei o textfield com a variavel respoata

Comment: Então, pode ser isto ... Mas eu só gostaria que você me mandasse o código inteiro para eu entender o que você está querendo me mostrar, desde a parte da criação das Arrays ...

Comment: Editei colocando o código completo do botão